# How does "this" keyword work in the particular way?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor, overwrite

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, but got stuck with a problem (more with misunderstanding "this" keyword) that doesn't give me move on.

I've watched a lot of content about it and barely understood it, but still have some troubles.

I have some code:

```
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.changeName = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

What do we use "this" here for?
As I understood we use "this" to create variable inside function constructor and give it value of our "name" parameter that we could refer to it. Am I right?

Then I have this code:

```
var p1 = new Person ("John", 30);
p1.changeName ("Jane");
console.log(p1.name);
```

As I sorted out here, we call method that overwrites our variable that we created to refer to. But it doesn't change actual parameter. So if it's right why do we use it? Doesn't it matter to have actual "name" parameter changed?

The whole code is from teaching app!

Comment: What do you mean by *"But it doesn't change actual parameter."*? It's true, it doesn't, but it seems like an odd thing to highlight...?

Comment: Try `this.changeName = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
  }.bind(this)` or `this.changeName = (name) = > {
    this.name = name;
  }` or `const self = this; this.changeName = function (name) {
    self.name = name;
  }`.

Comment: I wonder if does it still store like the first value and just show us the second one which is changed?

Comment: @connexo Why? `this`/ The `name` is changed to `"Jane"`. `this` inside `changeName` will refer to the the instance of the class.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @DavvaQuantie Your question is unclear. Please be specific what you don't understand. Do you want to know how the `name` is changed to  `"Jane"`?

Comment: @MaheerAli There is no class here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @DavvaQuantie — Why would it store the original value after you overwrote it?

Comment: @connexo — Constructor functions are JavaScript classes. (The `class` keyword is just new and alternative syntax for creating them).

Comment: @Quentin That is simply imprecise. Constructor functions are the JavaScript *equivalent* of the classes concept known from other languages.

Comment: @connexo But that doesnot justify your answer. Whether there are classes or not.

Answer (score 0):

> So if it's right why do we use it? Doesn't it matter to have actual "name" parameter changed?

No, there's no need to do that in this example. `changeName` changes the *property* on the object that was created by `new Person`.

It's true that that example code is a bit odd, because it creates the `changeName` function in the constructor but doesn't do the kinds of things you'd normally do when you create the function in the constructor. I'd expect that code to either be this, which puts the `changeName` on the prototype:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.changeName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
```

(or the `class` equivalent) or this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  };
  this.changeName = function(newName) {
    name = newName;
  };
  this.getAge = function() {
    return age;
  };
}
```

That code *does* update the parameter (which has no effect at all on the code calling `Person`). It doesn't create `name` and `age` properties at all; instead, it just makes their values accessible via `getName` and `getAge`. There's also a function to change `name` (`changeName`); but there's no function to change `age`. People write code like that so that `age` cannot be changed from outside code created within the `Person` constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you may misunderstand which parameter you actually change, so I rewrite it like so, holp this helps.

```js
function Person (argument_name, argument_age) {
  this.name = argument_name;
  this.age = argument_age;
  this.changeName = function (argument_change_name) {
    this.name = argument_change_name;
  }
}

let p1 = new Person ("John", 30);
p1.changeName ("Jane");
console.log(p1);
```

Answer (score -2):

The **this** keyword is used to create and assign values to variables in the class. It is again used to create functions, either getters or setters. So in your code **this.changeName** is a function that when passed a value will change the name of the person.
eg.

```js
var a = 5; // a is an integer
var b = "Han"; //b is a string
var c = function(name){
  //code here
} // then c is also a function;
```